# In simple terms, what is the meaning of "second-order local approximation"?

Tags: optimization, terminology, taylor-expansion

In simple terms, what is the meaning of “second-order local approximation”?

I have seen in used in Economics literature, but I presume it has a mathematical basis and meaning.

Comment: Some context would be handy.

Comment: @ Piotr Benedysiuk, see: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0165176583901088

Comment: It's basically just approximating a function around a point using a quadratic. (It is second-order because it makes use of the derivatives up to the second-order.)    There is a nice GIF showing different order approximations near the top of the Wikipedia page on Taylor series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is to match a quadratic (that is, a polynomial of degree 2, or **second order**) to the information near a particular (that is, **local**) point: you approximate the value, its rate of change (first derivative), and its acceleration (second derivative).  So, for instance, you can approximate $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ around $x=0$ as $1 + x - x^2/2$, and the approximation works reasonably well for quite a good distance:

[image: A comparison of sin(x)+cos(x) to 1 + x - x^2/2]

Look at how well the orange line matches the blue over $-0.5<x<0.5$.  A first order approximation won't do as well, going well too high at both $x=0.5$ and $x=-0.5$.

Comment: This is very clear and intuitive, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the Taylor series approximation to $f$ near $x_0$?  The second-order Taylor approximation of $f$ near $x_0$ is 
\begin{equation}
f(x) \approx f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)^T(x - x_0) + \frac12 (x - x_0)^T \nabla^2 f(x_0) (x - x_0).
\end{equation}
Here $\nabla^2 f(x_0)$ is the Hessian of $f$ at $x_0$.

This is a standard topic in calculus.